# Replicate "Run all specs" cypress test runner functionality via command line

Tags: cypress

I have several cypress spec files running against a web app in CI/CD build pipelines.

For whatever reason, there is a gap in time between each spec file is run in the pipeline, so the more spec files we add, the slower the build runs. I can see in the logs it's about 30s to a full minute between each spec file is run (I turned off the video record option to ensure that was not somehow related). Recently, it has begun to stall out completely and the build step fails from timing out.

To verify it wasn't related to the number of tests, I did an experiment by combining all the different tests into a single spec file and running only that file. This worked perfectly - because there was only a single spec file to load, the build did not experience any of those long pauses in between running multiple spec files.

Of course, placing all our tests into a single file is not ideal. I know with the cypress test runner there is a way to accomplish running all tests across multiple spec files as if they were in a single file using "Run all specs" button. From the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file):

*"But when you click on "Run all specs" button after cypress open, the Test Runner bundles and concatenates all specs together..."*

I want to accomplish the exact same thing through the command line. Does anyone know how to do this? Or accomplish the same thing in another way?

Using `cypress run` is not the equivalent. Although this command runs all tests, it still fires up each spec file separately (hence the delay issue in the pipeline).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like they don't want to do it that way. Sorry for not having a better answer.
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/run-all-specs/